# Can C++11 and C++17 Range-Based For Loop iterate to a specific position instead of full range of the map?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Are there versions of C++11 and C++17 Range-Based For Loop iterators that can iterate to a certain position in map?
For example, if a map has 10 key-value elements, then how can I iterate through only the first three key-value elements?
The following codes only iterate through the full range of the map.

```
//C++11    
for(auto m: mapData){
cout << m.first << ": " << m.second << endl;
}
//C++17
for(auto [key, val]: mapData){
    cout << key << ": " << val << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you require C++11 and C++17 specifically, not really. C++20 might have something though in the ranges library. Is C++20 also of interest to you?

Comment: a range based for loop is just synatctic sugar for a loop that uses begin and end iterators

Comment: No. You would need an external counter.

Comment: @user17732522 OK, so how it would work in C++20?

Comment: @InnocentBystander you mean adding if statment which break when the external counter reach the required limit?

Comment: @FadySamann If you're in C++20, you can probably construct a range from `map.begin()` and `next(map.begin(), n)` and iterate over that. However for maps, this would but iterating the sequence twice since the iterators are not random-access. You're better off just using a normal for-loop or `std::for_each_n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need an external counter to make early exit, eg:

```cpp
int n = 0;
for(auto&& [k, v] : map)
{
    if(++n > 10) break;
    std::cout << k << ": " << v << std::endl;
}
```

Or, if you are not afraid of copying the map, you can do:

```cpp
auto copy = std::map<...>{map.begin(), std::next(map.begin(), 10)};
for(auto&& [k, v] : copy)
{
    std::cout << k << ": " << v << std::endl;
}
```

Finally, if you **can** use C++20, then you can simply do this:

```cpp
#include <ranges>
for(auto&& [k, v] : map | std::views::take(10))
{
    std::cout << k << ": " << v << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ooo, `std::views::take(n)` -- I forgot about that. Nice

Answer (score 1):

Range-based for loops are just syntactic-sugar over normal `begin()` and `end()` calls. Your request of a partial iteration are complicated by the fact that `std::map` does not have random-access iterators -- which incurs a cost per iterator incrementing.

To avoid redundant costs, your best option would be to us range-based for loops to a specific counter with a `break`:

```cpp
auto count = 0;
for (const auto& [k,v] : map) {
  if (++count > n) { break; }
  // process 'k', 'v'
}
```

If you are looking for a "standard" approach, you can use [`std::for_each_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each_n) which lets you choose the length. You just need to ensure that the count doesn't exceed the length of container:

```cpp
auto length = std::min(map.size(), n);

std::for_each_n(map.begin(), n, [&](const auto& kv) {
    // process kv
});
```

Though the `std::for_each_n` approach is largely equivalent to the first approach with a counter.

---

If you expand to support [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), your options open up a bit since you can construct a [`std::ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange):

```cpp
for (const auto& [k,v] : std::ranges::subrange(map.begin(), std::advance(map.end(), n)) {
  // process 'k', 'v'
}
```

The downside with this approach is that `std::map` iterators are not random-access -- which means you are paying the cost of iterating the sequence **twice**. For the most part, this isn't really worth it just to try to leverage range-based `for` loops.

**Edit:** See @InnocentBystander's answer with `std::views::take(...)` as an alternative, which will effectively produce something equivalent to the `count`+`break`-based approach.